# Finding isomorphism question

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, set-theory

By given the next structures: $M_1=\langle\mathbb{N},<\rangle$, $M_2=\langle\mathbb{Z},<\rangle$, $M_3=\langle\mathbb{Q},<\rangle$, $M_4=\langle\mathbb{R},<\rangle$, $M_5=\langle\mathbb{R}^{+},<\rangle$,$M_6=\langle(0,1)\cup (1,2),<\rangle$, I need to find isomorphism between the models.

---

I have tried looking for the same cardinality of the models separately. Therefore, there is a chance for isomorphism between $M_1, M_2, \ M_3$, or between $M_4, M_5, \ M_6$. Now I find it hard to contradict isomorphism since I have to find a sentence that one satisfies and the other doesn't, for each couple of models. I believe finding a sentence isn't the fastest way to contradict isomorphism, so I will be happy to hear from you a piece of advice on this topic, and your full way of solving this question.

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than <, > does :)

Comment: @PatrickStevens I forgot to do so, you right! I usually add that.

Comment: @PatrickStevens it has fixed! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Welcome to MSE!

Hint:

To distinguish $M_1$, $M_2$, and $M_3$ you should try to find some simple features that intuitively make them different. Then you can formalize these features to find a sentence that distinguishes them.

For instance, notice $\mathbb{N}$ has a least element (either $0$ or $1$, depending on your definition of $\mathbb{N}$). This distinguishes it from both $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$. Can you make this precise (by finding a sentence describing the existence of a least element)?

To distinguish $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$, you might think about the "next integer". Is there such a thing as a "next rational"? Can you make this precise?

---

As for $M_4$, $M_5$, and $M_6$, there's some finesse needed.

First, does your $\mathbb{R}^+$ include $0$? If yes, then it has a least element. Can you show that it isn't isomorphic to either of the others (a similar argument to before will work). If $\mathbb{R}^+$ does *not* include $0$, then actually $M_4$ and $M_5$ *are* isomorphic! Can you find an explicit isomorphism? What are some nice monotone functions on $\mathbb{R}$ whose output is always positive?

$M_6$ is very subtle indeed. It turns out you won't be able to find a (first order) sentence which distinguishes it from $M_4$. This is because any two "dense linear orders without endpoints" agree on all first order sentences.

Of course, intuitively $M_6$ is "disconected" whereas $M_4$ and $M_5$ should be "connected". We can make this precise by thinking about *second order* sentences. In particular, notice every bounded subset of $M_4$ has a supremum. Can you find a (necessarily higher order) formula expressing this fact? Can you show that $M_6$ *doesn't* satisfy this property?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for putting in a lot of effort! :) For $M_5$ and $M_4$ the function is $f(x)=e^{x}$ right? because an exponent function is always positive and monotone for all negative and positive values of the domain.

Comment: In addition, you have said: "This is because any two "dense linear orders without endpoints agree on all first-order sentences.", what do you mean? because as I know there is a rule (Back-and-forth method) which says that: "any two countably infinite densely ordered sets (i.e., linearly ordered in such a way that between any two members there is another) without endpoints are isomorphic", but that is not the case. And again thank you so much!

Comment: Any two countable DLOs are isomorphic. So the theory is $\aleph_0$-categorical. Since there are no finite models, the theory is complete by the Los-Vaught test. But in a complete theory, any two models are elementary equivalent.

Comment: What are DLOs? you mean back and forth method?

Comment: Dense Liner Orders (without endpoints) are often called DLOs for short.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: However, I get a contradiction of this rule, since $\langle \mathbb{N},< \rangle$, $\langle \mathbb{Z},< \rangle$ which are not isomorphic but satisfy what this theorem says.